# Mixed content issue I have to resolve without changing the code of an application

Tags: html, web, iis, https, reverse-proxy

I'm currently working on a problem for my organization. We are hosting our own websites which are actually web portals for a software we make.
I run IIS and I'll try to explain as clear as possible whats the issue. Basically what IIS do is to run URL Rewrites. They point to http://*server ip*:9994 and rewrites 2 things. The server ip with the actual address name Also it applies SSL certificate for the https. Everything works fine untill you get to a specific tab.
That's the error I get:
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://*ip*:4320/ping”
So what i suspect is the following. We have a service which is named "ReportService" it is feeding information about a specific reports to a console app called "Jserver" . That happens on port 4320. The Jserver also runs the web application and the IIS's URL rewrites are pointing to it.

Is it possible to fix the issue without messing with the code of the applications. Maybe some type of proxy between the Jserver and the ReportService?

Every help or suggestion is appreciated.

I tried messing with the URL Rewrites but had no success. Probably because the requests are made from the ReportService to our software and from the ReportService to the Jservice.

```
     <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://"domainname":9994/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="https://"domainname"/webplus" />
</system.webServer>
```

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjYjN.png)

Comment: You want to fix this without changing the code. By definition, then, this is not a programming question. Try asking on [sf]

Comment: How did you set up the rewrite rules? Please provide us with the relevant code in the web.config file. Also, please provide details of your error page, including error status code, etc.

Comment: I added the rewrite web config you can takea look at it

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

A "Mixed Content" warning appears when an HTTPS page is required to load resources over HTTP.

Add this tag to your HTML to allow mixed content.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

But insecure resources can easily be altered by active attackers or eavesdropped by passive attackers, violating user expectations for the security of HTTPS pages.